# I have two breeds, one for students and other subjects. I want that subjects are fixed and the students move through the subjects

Tags: netlogo

I have two breeds, one for students and other subjects. I want that subjects are fixed and the students move through the subjects, when the student, pass, he can enroll each the subject by semester, like the follow.
But I need,more efficiently.

```
; create a list of subjects for each semester

to setup-subjects
  ;subjects semester1
  create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 11.43 set size 1.1 set name "calculoD" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
    create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 8.43 set size 1.1 set name "logica" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]

create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 5.43 set size 1.1 set name "prog_basic" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 2.43 set size 1.1 set name "sem_ingen" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 -0.43 set size 1.1 set name "catedra_fjc" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 -3.43 set size 1.1 set name "prod_comp_text" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 -6.43 set size 1.1 set name "catedra_contex" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -12.43 -9.43 set size 1.1 set name "elect_extrin1" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
  ;subjects semester2
  create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 11.43 set size 1.1 set name "calculoI" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
    create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 8.43 set size 1.1 set name "algebra_lineal" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
      create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 5.43 set size 1.1 set name "POO" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 2.43 set size 1.1 set name "fisicaI" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 -0.43 set size 1.1 set name "electiva_cb" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 -3.43 set size 1.1 set name "etica_bioetica" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 -6.43 set size 1.1 set name "seg_lengua1" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
        create-subjects 1[setxy -9.43 -9.43 set size 1.1 set name "grupo_trabajo1" set stateS -1
     set semester 1 set score 0.0]
  ask subjects[set color white]
end
```